# Convert geometry column and retain other columns

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

I have imported a shapefile (.shp) into R to define a set of polygons. The shapefile takes the form of a grouped dataframe with a`geometry` column containing a *MULTIPOLYGON* list of XY coordinates. I have added some extra columns of data to this dataframe:

```
ID   Value   geometry
A    5       MULTIPOLYGON (((519270 1639...
B    10      MULTIPOLYGON (((519553 1642...
C    25      MULTIPOLYGON (((519000 1666...
```

This works fine for generating static choropleth maps using `ggplot` and `geom_sf`. However, to generate dynamic maps using `leaflet` I need to convert the XY coordinates that define the polygons into lat/long coordinates.

I have tried using `st_transform` to do this and, while it does generate a set of polygons, I cannot colour those polygons as there are no values associated with them:

```
inter_map2 <- leaflet(df) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(data = st_transform(df$geometry, 4326), stroke = TRUE, weight = 0.5, opacity = 1, fillOpacity = 0.05, highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "red", weight = 2, bringToFront = TRUE))
```

I have also tried using `extract` but leaves the resulting lat and long columns with `NA` values:

```
df_latlong <- df %>%
  extract(geometry, c('lat', 'lon'), '\\((.*), (.*)\\)', convert = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to do this while also retaining the `ID` and `Value` columns associated with the polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sf` object is bit more than just a regular tibble / dataframe with coordinates in a column named `geometry`, attributes and geometries are meant to be used together and in most cases there's no reason to split those by force.

`extract()` will not work as geometry is not really a string, printing it just outputs geometries as a WKT (well-known-text). And by calling `st_transform(df$geometry, 4326)` you are indeed left with just the transformed geometry list, attribute columns get dropped; it has its uses but its more common to transform the sf objects and not just the geometry column, i.e. do `st_transform(df, 4326)`.

`data` parameter in `leaflet()` sets the default data object, in your case it's `df`. In following `addPolygons()` calls you don't need to override it unless you want to add more layers, just use formula notation (~) and reference `df` columns. Something like this:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

# sf exampl shapefile, tranform to projected CRS
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% st_transform(6542)
nc[,1:2]
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 123829.8 ymin: 14740.06 xmax: 930518.6 ymax: 318255.5
#> Projected CRS: NAD83(2011) / North Carolina
#> First 10 features:
#>     AREA PERIMETER                       geometry
#> 1  0.114     1.442 MULTIPOLYGON (((387344.7 27...
#> 2  0.061     1.231 MULTIPOLYGON (((408601.4 29...
#> 3  0.143     1.630 MULTIPOLYGON (((478715.7 27...
#> 4  0.070     2.968 MULTIPOLYGON (((878193.4 28...
#> 5  0.153     2.206 MULTIPOLYGON (((769834.9 27...
#> 6  0.097     1.670 MULTIPOLYGON (((812327.7 27...
#> 7  0.062     1.547 MULTIPOLYGON (((878193.4 28...
#> 8  0.091     1.284 MULTIPOLYGON (((828444.5 29...
#> 9  0.118     1.421 MULTIPOLYGON (((671746.3 27...
#> 10 0.124     1.428 MULTIPOLYGON (((517435.1 27...

# pallete for leaflet from nc$AREA values
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "Greens",
  domain = nc$AREA
)

# pass transformed sf object directly to leaflet and in 
# addPolygons() reference its columns though formula (~) interface:
nc %>% 
  st_transform("WGS84") %>% 
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(color = ~pal(AREA), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>